# cannot understand what is wrong with this simple pymongo code

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My virtual machine always return an empty pointer for queries. Is something wrong with the server or my code?

My code:

[image: Code]

My virtual machines screen:

[image: virtual machine]

Comment: always include formatted code on your question, not screen shots of it. Helps other to try and debug it.

Comment: Scroll through http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html - I believe it will answer your question. Specifically look at "Querying for More Than One Document" section.

Comment: @wazy: do you see anything wrong though? i was following a udemy.com tutorial video, i tried to write exact same code as the guy in video. But am not getting results when i run

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, this is what I can understand from the code:

You are instantiating a client:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
```

I believe this works, given your second screenshot.

You are getting one of the data bases available for your client:

```
db = client["fullstack"]
```

This could be a potential problem. Are you sure you have the "fullstack" database? Maybe it is called "fullStack" or similar?

By default, if you do not have a "fullstack" data base, mongo will "create" it for you ( this may not be the right term. It's essentially like doing `use fullstack` in the mongo shell. Even if you don't have the "fullstack" db, it will work and you will be able to interact with it, but if you don't do anything to this db, it will disappear once you disconnect. )

You are trying to access a collection.

```
collection = db["students"]
```

Again, same issue as the db. Make sure it's "students" and not "Students" or something like that. Also, make sure you actually have records there.

I would advice doing something like:

`collection.insert_one({'test': 'record'})`

This is to make sure you actually have something there.

You could remove it afterwards by doing something like:

`collection.remove({'test': 'record'})`

Additionally, iterating over the cursor consumes the cursor. Since you do not have millions of records, you can do something like:

```
records = [record for record in collection.find({})]
```

This will keep all your records, in memory, in a list, which you can reuse.

Hope this helps!